# Unable to submit MR job to local setup from a webapp in Tomcat6 over ubuntu

Tags: tomcat, hadoop

Setup
Hadoop 1.1.2 is running on my local machine in pseudo-distributed mode. My webapp is running in tomcat6 over ubuntu. While it attempts to launch M/R job i see the following error

MyWebAppClass - Error while submitting hadoop job.

`Msg : org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=tomcat6, access=WRITE, inode="mapred":deepakkv:supergroup:rwxr-xr-x
org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=tomcat6, access=WRITE, inode="mapred":deepakkv:supergroup:rwxr-xr-x
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:95)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:57)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.mkdirs(DFSClient.java:1428)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.mkdirs(DistributedFileSystem.java:332)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:116)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:918)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:912)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:912)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:886)
        at`

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the owner and permissions of the directory to make it writable by the user.

```
bin/hadoop fs -chown tomcat6:tomcat6 /mapred
bin/hadoop fs -chmod 777 /mapred
```